# Auto indentation of #defines in VS CODE in a C++ file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

Here is what it currently looks like:

[image: Here is the image]

This is how I want it to look, without turning off the formatting features:

```
#define op ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0);cin.tie(0);cout.tie(0);
```

I want it to be in a single line, not in separate lines. Every time I save the file, it separates the line followed by white spaces and `\` at the end.

Comment: It looks like a problem with formatting extension you use and not about c++ or vs code.

Comment: Somewhat off-topic but you should probably put that in a `do { ... } while (0)`.

Comment: Never using a macro remotely similar to this looks like an excellent idea to me.